# SQL Server Indexes of DateTime Parts such as YEAR, MONTH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

Is it possible to have indexes on `DateTime` parts such as `DATEPART(YEAR, bp.[CreatedOn])` and `DATEPART(MONTH, bp.[CreatedOn])`? For example, I have the following T-SQL query:

```
DECLARE @year AS INT = 2012;
DECLARE @month AS INT = 8;

SELECT bp.Title, bp.CreatedOn FROM BlogPosts bp
WHERE (DATEPART(YEAR, bp.[CreatedOn]) = @year) AND (DATEPART(MONTH, bp.[CreatedOn]) = @month)
ORDER BY bp.CreatedOn;
```

And this is the execution plan I have: https://gist.github.com/3551450

Currently, there are not many records so it is not a big problem in terms of perf but the records will grow over the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd better construct criterion using datetime field:

```
declare @startMonth datetime = '20120801'

SELECT bp.Title, bp.CreatedOn 
  FROM BlogPosts bp
 WHERE bp.[CreatedOn] >= @startMonth
   AND bp.[CreatedOn] < dateadd (month, 1, @startMonth)
ORDER BY bp.CreatedOn;
```

This way query executor will be able to use index on CreatedOn.

Comment: hmm, nice idea! thx. So, it's not possible to create indexes on DateTime parts?

Comment: @tugberk It might, if you use persistent calculated column and index it.

Comment: -1. This has to run `dateadd` on all records so has to load all records (FULL TABLE SCAN)- very poor on performance. I bet you will see that on execution plan.

Comment: @Aliostad Are you sure? dateadd is on variable, not column.

Comment: @Aliostad this will not cause a full table scan if there is index on createdOn. And even if there isn't it will perform much better than (DATEPART(YEAR, bp.[CreatedOn]) = @year)....

Comment: I removed my downvote. but my suggestion is to store in different columns. It will have the best performance and I imagine there are more similar queries query is needed. Also the logic is not correct since only works if @startMonth is on 1st.

Comment: +1 This is just a simple range seek on an index. Don't see how adding separate year and month columns would help performance. If anything it would hinder performance as fewer rows per page.

Comment: @Aliostad I'm not sure of that. It would require composite index, using two not very selective columns. And @ startMonth is deliberately on 1st. To better model parameters one might use expression which t-clausen.dk has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes is it possible to put index on year and month. Here is an example:

```
create table testt(d datetime)
alter table testt add year as year(d) PERSISTED -- after marc_s advise. Thx
alter table testt add month as month(d) PERSISTED --

create index idx_year on testt(year)
create index idx_month on testt(month)
```

However I would always use a variation of Nikola's solution, so +1 to Nikola.

This is how you can rewrite month and year into a date:

```
DECLARE @year AS INT = 2012;
DECLARE @month AS INT = 8;
DECLARE @from DATE = dateadd(month, (@year-1900)*12 + @month - 1, 0)
```

Comment: Even better - make those computed columns **persisted** : `ALTER TABLE dbo.TestT ADD MyMonth AS MONTH(d) PERSISTED` - then their values won't be recalculated every time they're being accessed....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store date parts on different fields. Clearly this is a requirement which exist in your domain as such needs to be part of your model.

What you lose is that you have to construct the datetime for every model you load or you set the value but that would be a few CPU cycles.

Comment: This is just a simple query to bring back all items created in a given month. No need to store decomposed dates for this.

Comment: @MartinSmith this one yes. But as I said, there are going to be (I assume) more date related stuff so I suggested this.

Comment: Well, this would be possible but then (I guess) you need to create a trigger to keep the Year and Month columns in sync in case that the `CreatedOn` is changed (it is highly unlikely to be changed, though).

Comment: trigger?? really?? Not touching the tool of the devil.

Comment: A disadvantage of decomposing a DateTime to individual components for storage is that you then have to reinvent some of the validation that you get for free with DateTime.  For example, if you store month, day, and year separately, then it's possible to insert an invalid date like 1/32/2012.  Of course, you could add range check constraints, but that gets tricky with leap years (e.g., 2/29/2011).

Comment: @cbranch that happens in the model not in the DB. I use DB to store my data, do not need it to contain any logic.